# $timeout not working for running $digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am calling a chrome function which runs asynchronously, so I need to run the digest cycle to update scope variable values in the view. I tried using $timeout and $evalAsync, but they aren't working. If I call $scope.$apply directly at the end of the async callback it works. But this may cause conflict with Angular's digest cycle so I wanted to take the safer approach of timeout. The following is not working.

```
$timeout(function() {
  chrome.storage.local.get('jocularOctoLamp', function(items) {
    if (Object.keys(items.jocularOctoLamp).length) {
      accountUsername = items.jocularOctoLamp.accountUsername;
    } else {
      accountUsername = false;
    };
    if (accountUsername) {
      $scope.loggedIn = true;
      $scope.user = accountUsername;
      console.log('Value of loggedIn changed.');
    } else {
      $scope.loggedIn = false;
    }
  })
});
```

The following is working fine.

```
chrome.storage.local.get('jocularOctoLamp', function(items) {
  if (Object.keys(items.jocularOctoLamp).length) {
    accountUsername = items.jocularOctoLamp.accountUsername;
  } else {
    accountUsername = false;
  };
  if (accountUsername) {
    $scope.loggedIn = true;
    $scope.user = accountUsername;
    console.log('Value of loggedIn changed.');
  } else {
    $scope.loggedIn = false;
  }
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: *this may cause conflict with Angular's digest cycle*: why would it? You're calling $apply from a callback function executed by an asynchronous event that is out of the scope of angular. You **know** you won't be inside a digest cycle here.

Comment: @JBNizet I wasn't sure about the behavior of calling apply inside a non angular function. Thanks, but still why does timeout not work as it's expected to.

Comment: Calling $timeout just delays the execution of the call to `chrome.storage.local.get()`. The callback function passed is still executed by chrome, asynchronously, out of the scope of angular.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you actually make an answer?

Comment: @Xan you're right. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$timeout` just delays the execution of the call to `chrome.storage.local.get()`. The callback function passed is still executed by chrome, asynchronously, out of the scope of angular.

You shouldn't be afraid of calling `$apply()` in this case: you're calling it from a callback function executed by an asynchronous event that is out of the scope of angular. So you **know** you won't be inside a digest cycle here.